# Smoothing issues on blender sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting, smooth

Attached below are two screenshots of the mesh I'm trying to smooth down without any success.
I've tried:

1. Shift-left click
2. Smooth brush (adjusting strength & radius)
3. Remeshing + Shrinkwrap
4. Remeshing + Shrinkwrap + Bake

And they don't really seem to work. Feel free to download the attached blender file and try these methods, maybe I'm doing something wrong ..

Also, I'm trying to create a baby's skinfold on this mesh if anyone knows a good and efficient way to do so without rigging. Thanks for your help!
[image: Baby's arm]

[image: Baby's thigh skinfold]

Comment: hello, I can't see any link to your file

Comment: I can't seem to upload the blender file through blend-exchange. Any other way to do so?

Comment: you should be able to do it, you need to copy paste the URL of this page. But you can also use https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots sorry for the late reply. I just tried the website but it seems like the size limit is 24 MB. My blend file is 132MB. Also, what do I do after uploading it onto the pasteall.org/blend website? Where can I find the uploaded blend file and attach it to this forum?

Comment: you can just share the part with the problem. Once you've uploaded the file, copy paste here the URL it has generated

Comment: @moonboots sorry for the late reply, I was preparing for my finals. Now I'm back to this project. The part (with the problem) is the baby's body but that itself is still bigger than 25MB in size. Is there another way to share my blender file?

Comment: you can upload on wetransfer, send it to yourself, then share the link here

Comment: @moonboots Okay, done! Here is the link:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f1e675a8fcfdabd199c8b638e8a6dca420220502155557/9bd139e31faff96eb3d3224da979fb0d20220502155615/73b3e6

Comment: I'm afraid your file is a bit too heavy for my computer, I hope someone will help